# Proof of Lomnicki and Ulam on infinite product probability spaces

Tags: measure-theory, pr.probability, ho.history-overview

Given an arbitrary, nonempty family $(\Omega_i,\Sigma_i,\mu_i)_{i\in I}$ of probability spaces, there exists a probability measure $\mu$ on $\otimes_i\Sigma_i$ such that for every finite set $F\subseteq I$ $$\mu\Bigg(\bigcap_{i\in F}\pi^{-1}(A_i)\Bigg)=\prod_{i\in F}\mu_i(A_i),$$ when $A_i\in \Sigma_i$ for all $i\in F$.
The first valid proof of this theorem in full generality (without topological assumptions) seems to be due to Shizuo Kakutani in 1943 in [Notes on infinite product measure spaces, I](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-19/issue-3/Notes-on-infinite-product-measure-spaces-I/10.3792/pia/1195573633.full). Kakutani mentions in footnote 3 that a proof was attempted already in the 1934 paper [Sur la théorie de la mesure dans les espaces combinatoires et son application au calcul des probabilités. I. Variables indépendantes](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm23/fm23121.pdf) by Łomnicki and Ulam, but that there was mistake in their argument. This is echoed in the historical remarks of Bogachev's encyclopedic [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540345132) on measure theory. The following question is mainly motivated by historical curiosity:

> What is, in rough outline, the proof
> approach of Łomnicki and Ulam? What is
> their mistake?

I'm sorry that my ignorance of French keeps me from answering the question by simply studying the original paper.

Answer (score 1):

I found a pointer in

> Andersen, Erik Sparre, and Børge Jessen. [Some limit theorems on 
>   integrals in an abstract set](http://gymarkiv.sdu.dk/MFM/kdvs/mfm%2020-29/mfm-22-14.pdf). I kommission hos E. Munksgaard,
>   1946.

In the footnote on page 22, they locate the problem in Lemma 4 (on page 254) of the paper by Łomnicki and Ulam. Apparently, the index $N$ was chosen for two different things and then combined in a way that was invalid.